# Как удалить положительные элементы списка с формированием нового списка?

Tags: prolog, turbo-prolog

Здравствуйте! В прологе я новичок, списки пока плохо знаю. Подскажите, как удалить положительные элементы списка с формированием нового списка в Turbo Prolog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На SWI Prolog это выглядит так:

```
remove_positive([],[]). % База рекурсии
remove_positive([H|T],X):-H>0,remove_positive(T,X). % Исключаем положительный элемент из списка
remove_positive([H|X],[H|Y]):-remove_positive(X,Y). % Остальные элементы оставляем как есть
```

Первый параметр входной, второй выходной. Для Turbo Prolog это вроде бы нужно поместить в раздел clauses, в разделе goal для тестирования нужно написать что-то вроде

```
remove_positive([1,-1,4,-45,-6,4],X), write(X).
```

Comment: а как сформиорвать новый список?

Comment: а, все, спасибо, получилось)

Comment: На вход (первый параметр) подаете первоначальный список, на выходе (второй параметр) получаете новый список без положительных элементов.

Если ответ вам подходит, нажмите галочку рядом с ним)